# Three box plots on the same row on shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny

I want to ajust 3 gauge boxes on the same row using shiny app.

[image: Gauge]

I am trying to use the following example: [Fluid Grid System](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html)

However, all my attempts had no success on this C3 gauge box.

```
             fluidRow(column(width =8, box( C3GaugeOutput("gauge1","auto","auto")),
                                        box(C3GaugeOutput("gauge2","auto","auto")),
                                        box(C3GaugeOutput("gauge3","auto","auto"))))
```

I have tried to modify the width and height arguments, besides, column size per line, but the results remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve modifying the function into:

```
fluidRow(column(4,box(width = 15,C3GaugeOutput("gauge1","auto","auto"))),
                                        column(4,box(width = 15,C3GaugeOutput("gauge2","auto","auto"))),
                                 column(4,box(width = 15,C3GaugeOutput("gauge3","auto","auto"))))
```